# Spring Framework: No BeanFactory available anymore (probably due to serialization)

Tags: java, spring, frameworks, proxy, config

I am trying to convert an xml configured bean to JavaConfig.
The xml version is working, but I keep getting error when using the JavaConfig version:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No BeanFactory available anymore (probably due to serialization) - cannot resolve interceptor names [cacheAdvisor]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean.initializeAdvisorChain(ProxyFactoryBean.java:423)
```

Working xml configuration:

```
<bean id="contentLogic" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>cacheAdvisor</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="proxyInterfaces" value="com.company.logic.ContentLogic"/>
    <property name="target">
        <bean class="com.company.logic.ContentLogicImpl"/>
    </property> 
</bean>
```

Not working JavaConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ContentLogic getRealContentLogic() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        ProxyFactoryBean factory = new ProxyFactoryBean();
        factory.setInterceptorNames(new String[]{"cacheAdvisor"});
        factory.setTargetClass(ContentLogicImpl.class);
        factory.setProxyInterfaces(new Class[]{ContentLogic.class});
        return (ContentLogic) factory.getObject();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a new `ProxyFactoryBean` yourself without help of Spring. `ProxyFactoryBean` needs a `BeanFactory` which is injected through `setBeanFactory`. Actually `ProxyFactoryBean` implements `BeanFactoryAware`. That means, when Spring creates the instance, it automatically inject the `FactoryBean`. You would have to manage this yourself with the Java configuration. However I think the XML or annotation-based is more the standard way to config Spring. Why do you want here to convert it to Java-based config?

Comment: All other beans except this one has been removed from XML, since we now use @Component. So it would be nice to get rid of the final one :-)
I will try your suggestion and report back!

Comment: Worked great, thanks!
Here is the added code: 
    factory.setBeanFactory(beanFactory);